# PrimeVue editingRows

Tags: datatable, vuejs3, editmode, primevue

I was hoping someone could help me with *PrimeVue DataTable* editing mode. On the docs for the DataTable it is stated that

> Row Editing is defined by setting `cellEdit` as "row", defining `editingRows` with the v-model directive to hold the reference to the editing rows and adding a row editor column to provide the editing controls. Note that since `editingRows` is two-way binding enabled, you may use it to initially display one or more rows in editing more or programmatically toggle row editing.

Does anyone have a working example on how I could use the `editingRows` to programmatically toggle editing in the newly added row? I tried updating this variable by pushing the values of the new row into `editingRows` array but this did not change anything on the page (I tried using *nextTick*), just meant that when I then manually triggered the row edit I had to cancel it twice to empty the array.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone struggling with the same issue, turns out that the solution was quite simple and required direct re-assignment to `this.editingRows` - I previously tried adding a new value to it by using `push`.

Here's how I did it (while keeping rows - which were in edit mode - in editing mode):

`this.editingRows = [...this.editingRows, this.newRow]`